# iPhone app does not run well on iPads, which for some reason is required during app review?

Tags: ios, xcode

I made an iPhone app, which runs perfectly on iPhone 5 to iPhone 7 Plus. My SKSpriteNodes & Labels fit perfectly on the screen, along with the banner ads/interstitials.

But when I run on an iPad? All the buttons/labels are either off the screen or look uncentered. I've just now seen that Apple requires iPhone apps to run on iPads in iPhone mode for some reason (I don't want people with iPads to be able to run my app), and I think they might reject mine because it is extremely hard to play my game due to certain buttons being off the screen. I've tried setting the scale mode of the buttons and such but it doesn't do anything. I've also mentioned in the notes to the review team that my app is not meant to be ran on iPads.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may not intend for the app to be ran on iPads but it will increase your revenues gained by any ads, in app purchases, or app purchase(downloads) if it does. I would recommend you continue to work on the project until you have everything looking the same on all size devices. Or at least have some kind of variation based on the device to handle this. It is very common to have to create Constraint variables that change based on device size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do intend one day to make this app iPad compatable, but for now I just need to get it accepted by Apple. If they are testing on iPads, there are certain buttons that go off the screen (only on iPads), making my game almost unplayable. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: All iPhone-only apps must work as-is when run on iPads. On an iPad, an iPhone-only app will be run in an iPhone compatibility mode. The app will run just as it would on a 3.5" iPhone. So get your app to work on the small iPhone and it will work properly on iPads.

Comment: @rmaddy I have tried it on every single iPhone available in Xcode currently (SE, 5 - 7 plus), and it looks flawless on all of them. Only when it is ran on an iPad the nodes arent positioned correctly. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You need to test it on a 3.5" iPhone/Sim such as the iPhone 4s or simply use an iPad/iPad Sim. Either way, your app must be made to work on the 3.5" screen, not just 4" and larger screens.

Comment: Currently downloading a 3.5" simulator, but the iPad air seems like itll be the same. On the iPad 12.7" my app runs fine, but down the the 9" one and it starts to cut off some of the bottom. Do I have to set some special property in my sks scene or something?

Comment: My issue was that my scene sizes were slightly off from the iPhone 4s' size. Grrr, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

My scene sizes were slightly off from the iPhone 4s' size (640x960). My issue is fixed now! Hope this helps someone in the future.